# minimize memory consumption when dealing with python list assignment

Tags: python, algorithm, memory

I have two high-dimension lists of integers. The dimension of each list is over 200000. My task is like this:
given two list

```
a = [None, 0, None, None, 0, None, None, None, 0, None, None, None, None, None, 0,...]
b = [7 1 4 8 2 1 1 1 1 6 1 6 1 4 4 1 1 6 6 7 4 4 7 5...]
```

the number of `None`equals to the length of b

**My question** is how to replace all `None` of `a` with each element in `b`using ***minimum memory***.

My method is

```
j = 0
for i in range(len(a)):
    if a[i] == None:
        while j < len(b):   
            a[i] = b[j]
            break
        j = j+1
```

Since my program consumes memory much, I really need to save memory use. Could you please give me some ideas on how to save the memory in this situation?

Comment: to check the memory maybe can be useful this package https://github.com/fabianp/memory_profiler

Comment: Which version of Python are you using, 2 or 3? If this is Python 2, then you should use `xrange` instead of `range`, since that's the only thing in your code that uses any significant amount of memory. The arrays `a` and `b` occupy memory too, of course, but since those are the inputs you can't avoid that in this code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make an iterator from `b`, then in a list comprehension if the current element of `a` is `None`, you can `next(b_iter)` to grab the next item.

```
b_iter = iter(b)
a = [next(b_iter) if i is None else i for i in a]
```

As an example

```
>>> a = [None, 0, None, None, 0, None, None, None, 0, None, None, None, None, None, 0]
>>> b = [7, 1, 4, 8, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 6, 1]
>>> b_iter = iter(b)
>>> [next(b_iter) if i is None else i for i in a]
[7, 0, 1, 4, 0, 8, 2, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 6, 1, 0]
```

Comment: Thank you for your kind answer. But could you please explain more on why using iterator makes memory consumption minimum?

Comment: @allenwang Because an iterator only accesses one element at a time. It doesn't create an entire copy of the list. It simply walks (or iterates) along a sequence, and retrieves an element each time you request one, in this case by using the function `next`